# Align columns from tbody under their column title in thead

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, display

At the beginning it was a simple table with no css styling on it.

The first requirement was to make it scrollable and with a fixed height.

In order do to that it was added:

```
height: 275px;
overflow: scroll;
```

It wasn't enough, it also needed `display: block;`.

Now, the thead looks bad, so I added `display: table;` to it.

It looks quite good but it still has a problem, the columns are not aligned vertically.

For example, the column with the title **Test2** should have under it the column with **$test** but that it's not happening.

Is there a way to align those columns and keep the scrolling functionality?

```css
.my-table {
  width: 100%;
}

.my-thead {
  display: table;
}

.my-tbody {
  display: block;
    height: 275px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<table class="my-table">
  <thead class="my-thead">
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
      <th>Column</th>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test2</th>
      <th>Priceeeee</th>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="my-tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>aaaaaaaa</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>12314332</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>33333324</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>March</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>April</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>May</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>June</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>August</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>September</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>October</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>October</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>October</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>October</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>October</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>October</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>October</td>
      <td>testesttest</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

columns can be vertically aligned by adding `width` property. Add the below given css:

```
th {
  min-width: 130px;
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  width: 130px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```css
.my-table {
  width: 100%;
}

.my-thead {
  display: table;
}

.my-tbody {
  display: block;
  height: 275px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

th {
  min-width: 130px;
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  width: 130px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table class="my-table">
    <thead class="my-thead">
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Column</th>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Test2</th>
        <th>Priceeeee</th>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="my-tbody">
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>12314332</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>33333324</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>March</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>April</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>May</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>June</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>August</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>September</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>October</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>October</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>October</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>October</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>October</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>October</td>
        <td>$80</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>October</td>
        <td>testesttest</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>$test</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border:solid 1px black;
}

thead th {
    background-color:grey;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px 3px 4px 4px;
    text-align: left; 
    width: 80px;
}
thead{
display:block;
}
tbody {
  height: 275px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  display:block;
}


tbody td {
    background: #FFF;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding: 4px 3px 4px 4px;
}

th,td{
    width: 80px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table class="my-table">
  <thead class="my-thead">
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
      <th>Column</th>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test2</th>
      <th>Priceeeee</th>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="my-tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>aaaaaaaa</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>12314332</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>33333324</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>March</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>April</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>May</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>June</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>August</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>September</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>October</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>October</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>October</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>October</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$test</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>October</td>
      <td>$80</td>      
      <td>test</td>
      <td>$1
```